# C# Multiple objects in dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

in my asp.net application, i am retrieving the data from a textbox and trying to make a dictionary object.

```
protected void btnAddBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Barcodes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
        {
            ShowMessage("Please enter or scan barcode");
            return;
        }
        // Saving the Barcodes at first
        else if (i < Convert.ToInt32(hdnTotalItems.Value))
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Barcodes.Add(i, txtBarcode.Text);
                lblItemsScanned.Text = i.ToString();
                Session["Barcodes"] = Barcodes;

                txtBarcode.Text = string.Empty;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else { 

        }

    }
```

First time the data is getting saved in dictionary, but second time the dictionary is getting updated with the first one. I want to keep all them.

Any kind of help will be gracefully accepted.

Comment: You create a new instance every time. create a new one only when there isn't one on the session

Comment: You are declaring your dictionary inside the method as "local" var. You have to put it inside the object as field

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary you defined is local method variable which is initiated each time the method is called so your previous data will be lost. Event the page does not maintain the state of page data members. You can store it in `ViewState`, `Session` or `Application` object depending on where you need it later. You can also think of storing it on some persistent medium like database.

If you want it for same page then you can use `ViewState`. If you want it for current user session and accessible across pages then you can put it in `Session`. Putting it in `Application` object will make it accessible across pages and users.

You can make property over Application collection like this.

```
public Dictionary<int, string> Barcodes
{
    get { return (Dictionary<int, string>)Application["Barcodes"]; }
    set { Application["Barcodes"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<int, string> Barcodes = new Dictionary<int, string>();` is executed every time. So you initialise the session variable every time. you need to check if it exists first.

try this:

```
if(Session["Barcodes"]==null)
  Session["Barcodes] = new Dictionary<int, string>();

Barcodes = (Dictionary<int,string>)Session["Barcodes"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary object **Barcodes** is getting instantiated every time when you click. To avoid that, modify the code as below,

```
protected void btnAddBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Barcodes = Session["Barcodes"] == null ? new Dictionary<int, string>() : (Dictionary<int,string>)Session["Barcodes"];
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
        {
            ShowMessage("Please enter or scan barcode");
            return;
        }
        // Saving the Barcodes at first
        else if (i < Convert.ToInt32(hdnTotalItems.Value))
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Barcodes.Add(i, txtBarcode.Text);
                lblItemsScanned.Text = i.ToString();
                Session["Barcodes"] = Barcodes;

                txtBarcode.Text = string.Empty;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else { 

        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you should use session 
first you should save Dictionay into session and then in next ittration get it from session
use this simple code

```
if(Session["Barcodes"]==null)
  Session["Barcodes] = new Dictionary<int, string>();

Barcodes = (Dictionary<int,string>)Session["Barcodes"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
protected void btnAddBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Barcodes;

        if (Session["Barcodes"] == null)
        {
            Barcodes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        }
        else
        {
            Barcodes = (Dictionary<int, string>)Session["Barcodes"];
        }

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBarcode.Text.Trim()))
        {
            ShowMessage("Please enter or scan barcode");
            return;
        }
        // Saving the Barcodes at first
        else if (i < Convert.ToInt32(hdnTotalItems.Value))
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Barcodes.Add(i, txtBarcode.Text);
                lblItemsScanned.Text = i.ToString();
                Session["Barcodes"] = Barcodes;

                txtBarcode.Text = string.Empty;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else 
        { 

        }

    }
    catch(Exception) {}
}
```